# Python program Terminated due to timeout

Tags: python, stack, timeout, termination

I am trying to solve a question from hackerrank and when I submit my solution, I get an error stating "Terminated due to timeout".

Please check the code and suggest me how to optimize.

**Statement :**
You have an empty sequence, and you will be given  queries. Each query is one of these three types:

1 x  -Push the element x into the stack.
2    -Delete the element present at the top of the stack.
3    -Print the maximum element in the stack.

**Input Format**

The first line of input contains an integer, . The next  lines each contain an above mentioned query. (It is guaranteed that each query is valid.)

**Output Format**

For each type  query, print the maximum element in the stack on a new line.

**Sample Input**

10
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
3

**Sample Output**

26
91

**My code :**

```
n = int(input())
stack = []

for i in range(n):
     l = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
     if l[0] == 1:
        stack.append(l[1])
    elif l[0] == 2:
        stack.pop()
    elif l[0] == 3:
        print(max(stack))
```

Comment: your `sample input` is incomplete or not properly formatted i guess. please post it correctly

Comment: I often see hackerrank problems which are not explicit about the corner cases and their answer : can n be 0 ? Can the 3 query happens on a empty stack ? If there is no 3 in the input, do you have to print something special ?

Comment: @Raman did you find the answer?

Comment: @FarheenNilofer No, I tried all the suggested solutions but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right, you specify the counter i but never use it. This would produce no output or anything if your first input isn't one of the commands which it obviously isn't.

```
n = int(input())
stack = []

for i in range(n):
     l = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
     if l[i] == 1:
        stack.append(l[i+1])
    elif l[i] == 2:
        stack.pop()
    elif l[i] == 3:
        print(max(stack))
```

Comment: read the input format it says `The first line of input contains an integer, . The next lines each contain an above mentioned query. (It is guaranteed that each query is valid.)`  example input that was mentioned in the question was not properly formatted.

Comment: Your code is wrong because l consists of either 1 or 2 elements after split() does its work . So specifying l[i] will cause 'list index out of range' error

Comment: @Raman did you check my code? if its correct you should accept it as answer

Comment: Ah yeah you're right @Raman. What if you take the splitting out of the for loop and have it make a complete array with every sign? Then take the length of this array (l) instead of n and it should work. Or am I doing a mistake somewhere again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper input with expected output.

```
"""
    proper input format for you problem
    10
    1 97
    2
    1 20
    2
    1 26
    1 20
    2
    3
    1 91
    3
    """

    n = int(raw_input())
        stack = []
        while n > 0:
            # read the option here it may be of form 1 x or 2 or 3
            option = map(int,raw_input().split())
            # if it has two elements that means it was of form 1 x,
            # so, push the second element on stack (stack[1])
            if len(option) > 1:
                stack.append(option[1] )
            else:
                # if option is 2 there will only be one element 
                # in option ( which is option[0]
                # so, remove from top of stack
                if option[0] == 2:
                    del stack[-1]
                else:
                    print max(stack)
            n = n-1
```